# How to create an equation for a line in three dimensions given three points

Tags: math, line

From the equation of a three dimensional line:

```
 f(x,y,z) = A*x + B*y + C*z + D = 0
```

The normal is

```
 grad f = [A,B,C]
```

The Normal thru Point (x0,y0,z0) is
     [A  .[x-x0
      B    y-y0
      C]   z-z0] = A*(x-x0) + B*(y-y0) + C*(z-z0)= 0

My question is with given three points (x0,y0,z0),(x1,y1,z1), and (x2,y2,z2)
How do you setup the matrix:

```
[a0 b0 c0 d0
 a1 b1 c1 d1
 a2 b2 c2 d2]
```

To solve for A,B,C,D?

Comment: is there a specific language your targeting?

Comment: Any, VB is preferred but c# is ok.

Comment: A line in 2D goes through two points only, same in 3D. So you need linear regression / least squares fitting?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about geometry and [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Comment: you are mixing line and plane .... The equation you have provided is for 3D plane. 3D lineis  from 2 points `A,B` is  `P(t) = A + (B-A)*t` where `P(t)` is any point on line while `t=<0,1>`. This is called linear interpolation.

Answer (score 3):

The equation you wrote down is for a plane. One equation for 3 variables results in general in a 2 dimensional surface. The plane equation for given 3 points can be written as the determinant equation

```
    | x1  x2  x3  x |
0 = | y1  y2  y3  y |
    | z1  z2  z3  z |
    |  1   1   1  1 |
```